# how to inject mock into private method?

Tags: java, junit, mocking

the mock object is working fine when i access public methods. but it s not working when i access private method.

**My Mock Class:**

```
@component
public class Test{

public List<String> list(){
 // some function}
}
```

**My Main Class:**

```
@component
public class Test2{
private string method(String method){
//here where i have to use mock object
//some function
}
}
```

**My TestCases:**

```
public class JunitTestCases{

@Mock
Test test;

@Autowired
@InjectMocks
Test2 test2
public void Oncall{
Test2 test=new Test2();
Method method=Test2.class.getDeclaredMethod("method",String.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(test, "data");}
}
```

i am getting the following errors.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.TestCases.method(TestClass.java:198)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.MainClass.validate(MainClass.java:149)
... 21 more
```

any suggestion? how can i make it work?

Comment: without any code, no one can answer that

Comment: How are you calling a private method on a mock? A private method can only be called from within the same class or by using reflection. If you are using reflection you are going to have problems with mocks anyway.

Comment: sorry for missing my code part. i have added my codes.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo classs For Writing Tests**

```
public class PowerMockDemo {

    public Point callPrivateMethod() {
        return privateMethod(new Point(1, 1));
    }

    private Point privateMethod(Point point) {
        return new Point(point.getX() + 1, point.getY() + 1);
    }
}
```

**Test Class For Demo class**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PowerMockDemo.class)
public class PowerMockDemoTest {

    private PowerMockDemo powerMockDemoSpy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        powerMockDemoSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new PowerMockDemo());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockPrivateMethod() throws Exception {
        Point mockPoint = mock(Point.class);

        PowerMockito.doReturn(mockPoint)
            .when(powerMockDemoSpy, "privateMethod", anyObject());

        Point actualMockPoint = powerMockDemoSpy.callPrivateMethod();

        assertThat(actualMockPoint, is(mockPoint));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the invoke method your using ***string.class[paramter]*** instead of  **Class[][parameterArray].**

*no need create the other object for Test2.class already your used @injectMocks just use the variable in the invoke method* .

```
public class JunitTestCases{

@Mock
Test test;

@InjectMocks
Test2 test2;

@Test
public void Oncall{

     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      Class<?>[] params = new Class<?>[]{String.class};
      Method method=Test2.class.getDeclaredMethod("method",params);
       method.setAccessible(true);
       method.invoke(test2, "data");

    }
}
```