# How to mock private method of an abstract class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermockito

```
public abstract class ClassA extends {

        public String getName(){
          String lastName = getLastName();
          return "Language"+lastName;
        }

        private String getLastName(){
          return "Java";
        }
}
```

I am writing the test for getName . I want to mock getLastName method . How can i do it ?

Comment: You're not usually supposed to mock private methods. What would be the advantage of mocking it anyway, since it just returns `"Java"`? How are you trying to test the method? Are you trying to test an abstract class?

Comment: I just have given an example . The orignal private method which i want to wrote UT is much complex

Comment: A good resource to go through : https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mock-private-static-void-methods-mockito/amp/

Answer (score 0):

You can try approach from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55096247/9690114) answer.

However, if logic in private method is complex and class needs separate testing for it, it's a sure sign that you need some refactoring.

According to SOLID principles your private method should be public, and also should be placed in derived class.

```java
public abstract class ClassA {
  private final LastNameProvider provider;

  public ClassA(LastNameProvider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  public String getName() {
    String lastName = provider.getLastName();
    return "Language"+lastName;
  }
}

public interface LastNameProvider {
  String getLastName()
}

public class JavaLastNameProvider {
  private String getLastName(){
    return "Java";
  }
}
```

With that approach you can easily replace `provider` in `ClassA` with another one for testing, or you can mock it with `Mockito` and so on.